# Dynamic Subdomains with "hello world" application on Google App Engine + webbapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, subdomain, webapp2, cname

I have a few problems. I work and could not figure out for days.

Objective: to create subdomains dynamically on Google App Engine.

I'm just a "hello world" I would like to recommend for implementation, can take care of the rest.

1-http://eqsudmoain.appid.appspot.com
written = "eqsubdomain"

2-http://appid.appspot.com
written = "hello world"

I want to just do them, I need your help.
I find the documentation of this code, but rather than dynamic.

here's code;
https://snipt.net/mehmetkose/google-app-engine-dynamic-subdomains-question/?key=7a99428d29d9aa8376158a22dbb63c94

which is also a domain registrar to use the cname Would you recommend?
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set domains dynamically in code.

However you can have different subdomains, by setting different app versions. This how various versions are mapped (note that version is a string not a number):

```
http://1.appid.appspot.com   // version "1"

http://eqsudmoain.appid.appspot.com   // version "eqsudmoain"

http://appid.appspot.com   // default version
```

You can [set version in app.yaml](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Required_Elements). You set default version in Admin - Versions.

So, what you propose is possible, by uploading code multiple times under different versions, then using example code in the link to distinguish between subdomains in code.

**Edit:**

You can not have dynamic subdomain mapping on `*.appid.appspot.com`, but you can have [wildcard DNS mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) on your own domain, i.e. `*.yourdomain.com`. Then in code you can check the host and and route request to the right code.

Comment: I am going to read document. app.yaml I guess makes sense to use. just like htaccess. but I do not want a static subdomain.

eg

user1.example.com or user1.appid.appspot.com
user2.example.com or user2.appid.appspot.com
tag2.example.com or tag2.appid.appspot.com
tag3.example.com or tag3.appid.appspot.com

I just want to catch up subdomains.
<subdomain>. appid.appspot.com

handler need only two.
1. handler for the main domain.
http://appid.appspot.com

Handler for 2.subdomainler
http://subdomain.appid.appspot.com

sorry English is not good. I'm working on.

Comment: There are no dynamic subdomains on GAE, except for the static version mapping I mentioned above. However you can have your own wildcard domain (e.g. *.yourdomain.com) that maps to appid.appspot.com: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record